# Debian jessie Logitech G35 microphone not working

Tags: debian, audio, pulseaudio

I'm on Debian jessie with KDE. I have a Logitech G35 headset and even managed to enable surround sound.

Now I noticed that the microphone isn't muted. I'm pretty sure that it is not muted and set as the default device.

My KDE does use phonon, phonon uses the VLC backend and VLC should use pulseaudio.

Does anyone know how i can get the microphone to work?